# marked(): input parameter is of type [object Function], string expected

Tags: vue.js

In my assets folder I have some markdown files. I would like to read the file content, convert it to valid HTML and display it within a div container.

Before reading the file content I tried a markdown parser and took `marked` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked).

When trying to use it I get this error

> marked(): input parameter is of type [object Function], string
>   expected

at

[image]

I created an minimalistic example where you can see the error

https://codesandbox.io/s/m36z064pn9

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> marked(): input parameter is of type [object Function], string expected

Seems that string is expected, where you pass an object?

However, just simply require the `marked` package in your App.vue component, where you are using it:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app"><div v-html="previewText"></div></div>
</template>

<script>
  let marked = require("marked");

  export default {
    name: "app",
    data() {
      return {
        md_text: "# Marked in browser\n\nRenderedd by **marked**."
      };
    },
    computed: {
      previewText() {
        return marked(this.md_text);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

[Check the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qw31x714x)

[Reference](https://medium.com/chingu/markdown-previewer-using-vuejs-c4ea88457061)